# Xamarin workflow on Windows

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I'm aware that a Mac or a Mac service e.g. MacInCloud.com is necessary for building and submitting iOS apps.

My question is about the actual workflow of building an app on Windows using Xamarin on Visual Studio 2017.

We need to write code, test and debug throughout development cycle. How does this work with Xamarin running on Windows? How would I actually see what my mobile app looks like or behaves during the actual development cycle?

While developing my web apps in Visual Studio, there are many trips back and forth to the browsers and back to VS in order for me to see the results of my code. How does this work with Xamarin running on Windows? Is Xamarin Live Player the only option for development cycle? Is there a solution through MacInCloud or similar services so that tethering a device to dev machine is not necessary?

I'm just trying to understand how a healthy development cycle is created for Xamarin developers on Windows.

Comment: You can use Xamarin Live Player for *limited* UI design preview/edit/preview cycles, but for a "healthy development cycle" with `Xamarin.iOS` on Windows you will need a full-time connected Mac for the builds, the iPhone/iPad simulators, physical device testing, etc... In the end, full-time pairing *at least* a headless MacMini will be a wise investment to achieving that "healthy development cycle". Remember the remote iOS simulator on Windows is only provided via VS Enterprise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer your question in few section: Coding, Debug, Test

### Coding

You will be using Visual Studio to write your codes. iOS and Android code will be written in C#. You will get access to UI Designer for both iOS and Android to edit the layout files and storyboard/xibs. For 3rd party library, there is NuGet to serve your needs.

### Debug

You can use Xamarin Live Player without connection to a Mac/MacInCloud for basic preview. However, some features of iOS is not available in Xamarin Live Player (e.g. xibs files not supported...).

If you setup with connection to a Mac, you will be able to see a list of Simulator that available in the Mac you connected to. By default, if you debug it, the simulator will still show up in the Mac. Then you will need to VMWare or remote into the Mac to check the simulator output. If you have Visual Studio Enterprise license, you can get access to a Remote iOS Simulator feature. You will need to turn the option ON. After that, you will able to see a remote iOS Simulator showing in your Windows machine without the needs to remote into Mac machine anymore. For debugging in actual iOS devices, you will still need to plug your device into the Mac. Previously (more than 1 years ago), Xamarin announce that they are working on "iOS USB remoting" to allow you to plug in iOS device into Windows machine and debug on it. But it is not release until now.

For Android, you can get access to Android Emulator Manager to add emulator to debug or you can deploy apps to physical phone just like what you can do with Android Studio.

### Test

I will be referring to Xamarin.UITest for this part. You will be able to write UITest code in C# inside Visual Studio. Xamarin have product "Xamarin Test Cloud" to allow you to upload test code and binary and then run your test in cloud periodically. If you want to run the test locally in your machine, you will only able to run Android UITest in windows machine. To run iOS UITest locally, you will only able to run it in Mac machine. Using a Mac, you can also run Android UITest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simulator/emulator instead of a device. For iOS, the simulator would run on the Mac Build Host that you are connected to. You can select the option for "Remote iOS simulator" in Visual Studio -> Xamarin.iOS options and you'll be able to interact with the simulator without having to RDP/VNC/look at the mac. For android, you can just run an emulator in Window and interact with it like that. Using your web apps comparison, you would use a simulator/emulator instead of browser but, for the most part, the process would be similar.

Comment: Am I able to do this with a service like MacInCloud? If so, is it practical? If there’s a lot to upload, etc. it wouldn’t be very practical.

Comment: I haven't used MacInCloud for anything besides a CI build agent so I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I have been developing a Xamarin MVVM app targeted at iOS and Android.  I initially did the iOS development on Windows with VS 2022 and an iPhone attached via USB. I knew that I was going to have to eventually move to the Mac for final provisioning but I ended up taking that painful step earlier than planned because certain Xamarin features were just not working on Windows.  First I could not get my app icon to be anything other than the Xamarin default and then Xamarin.Essentials.FilePicker would not select a file:

https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1710

So after a week of struggling I finally got my project building and deploying on the Mac.  However, I am not nearly as comfortable working on the Mac as I am on Windows where I have all my familiar development tools.  So then the question was how to share the project files between the PC and the Mac so that I could edit and compile on the PC and then move to the Mac for final testing.

At first I tried iCloud but I could never get the files to sync reliably between the shared folder on the PC and the Mac.  I am used to Dropbox and OneDrive, which work as expected.  iCloud not so much.

So what I have been doing is committing and pushing the changes to github and then pulling the changes into the project on the Mac.  It is quick and has the added benefit of version control using an offsite server.  I am happy with this workflow and publishing the app on the Apple Store should be an easy task when that time comes.

Update:

This process is still working for me.  I have taken the additional step of doing the release configuration on VS Mac and publishing my app to App Store Connect.  That experience was convoluted and frustrating but it now works and I have people testing my app via TestFlight.

One hiccup is that when selecting Automatic iOS Bundle Signing in the project properties on VS Windows, this change gets pushed to the Mac side and causes a build error under Debug until I select the Automatic provisioning profile on the Mac.  Somehow it gets set to the Wildcard profile on the Windows side.